# Find last n days previous year DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find a way to calculate the sum of a value for the last n days of the previous year.

For example:
Lets assume n = 1

**today's date = 31.05.2017**, then my last date is **30.05.2017**(as n=1) then the sum for **31.05.2016** should be calculated.

Lets assume n = 5

**today's date = 31.05.2017**, then my last 5 days would be from **25.05.2017 to 30.05.2017** and then the sum for previous year last 5 days **25.05.2016 to 30.05.2016** should be calculated

Hope somebody can help me. Thanks.

Comment: How that N will be defined? Fixed inside the measure?

Comment: I have fix cards for last day and last 5 days. So this is fixed inside the measure @mkRabbani

Comment: you can calculate all dates first in the measure. then calculate the sum considering the date range.

Comment: the dates are dynamic @mkRabbani

Comment: Yes, compare to Today()

Comment: Share your PBIX and your expected results visually perhaps in excel for now?

Comment: How do you account for leap year? If today is `2020-03-01` `1st March,2020` and n=1, how that translate to last year?

Comment: We can ignore leap year for now @smpa01

Answer (score 0):

Here is some hints for generating the start and end date using DAX-

```
start_date = 

var n = 5

return TODAY() - n - 365
```

```
end_date = 

var n = 5

return TODAY() - 1 - 365
```

You can create them both inside a DAX and store them in 2 variable. Then calculate your desired value using the date range from start to end date.